# KTA Retention Policy Failures

Tags: kofax

I am getting following error from Retention Policy Deletion:

"Folder can’t be locked since its hierarchy contains locked document"

I am not sure how were these documents locked and how can I unlock them again.

Also, will unlocking them cause any data issues?

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retention Policies should only try to delete documents older than whatever you have configured (by date of last access).  So if this document were locked by normal use in the system, then it should have a recent last access date and not be ready for removal by retention policies.

Thus this is probably a problem occurring in the product.  You will need to open a technical support case so Kofax can diagnose the problem. In all likelihood, the support team can provide a SQL script to unlock the documents once they make sure there are no other problems.  But you should not do it on your own since it is not supported and, yes, it is possible to cause data issues by modifying the database.